# How to ignore hidden elements in a Bootstrap Button Group?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group containing 10 buttons.  Under certain screen widths (responsive) I hide some of these buttons with media queries.

The problem is that if I hide the last button the new last button's edges do not become rounded.

It's a difficult problem to describe, but very easy to show in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h48vmrw/).

My question: how can I add the rounded corners to the last *visible* button in the button group, rather than simply the last button, as it currently is.

Code from Fiddle below, as per SO's rules:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="sortBtns" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">First</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Second</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Third</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fourth</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fifth</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sixth</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" id="sortBtns" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">First</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Second</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Third</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fourth</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fifth</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="display:none;">Sixth</button>
</div>
```

Note the lack of rounded corners on 'fifth' in the second button group.

I can do this using JavaScript by adding a new class to the last visible element, but I'd rather not.  Is there a cleaner CSS-only solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide button in btn-group twitter-bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226268/hide-button-in-btn-group-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: @MartinLiversage I'm looking for a CSS solution, not JS.

Comment: The only thing that differentiates your question from the one I have linked to is that you want a CSS-only solution while the other just asks for a solution and by looking at the provided answers it seems like a CCS-only solution is not possible. And I am sure that others having a similar problem can benefit by looking at answers to both questions. For me the best solution was the highest rated answer to the linked question.

Comment: @MartinLiversage surely if one is looking for any solution and another is looking for CSS-only then both are viable, especially when the highest voted answer is _not_ CSS-only.  Whether it is possible or not is irrelevant, as in that case the best answer would say it isn't possible and why it isn't possible.

Comment: Another problem is that it changes the padding before the last item, making it so that if you try and center the buttons they will be off-center. Perhaps another solution is to have another hidden div with the buttons and move them to the btn-group with appendTo when making them visible and move them out when invisible. Because it semes like btn-group / btn-toolbar are simply not made to have hidden items.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind adding a dependency, I recommend AngularJS' `ng-if`. It comes in handy [when using css selectors that rely on an element's position within the DOM, such as the :first-child or :last-child pseudo-classes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf). It will remove the element from the DOM and allow you to achieve your goal.

Comment: I can easily do it in vanilla JavaScript with little overhead, was looking for a pure CSS solution though.  Doesn't look like one exists unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using jQuery:

```
$('.btn-group').has('.btn:hidden').find('.btn').css('border-radius', 0);
$('.btn-group').has('.btn:hidden').find('.btn:visible:first').css({
    'border-top-left-radius': '3px',
    'border-bottom-left-radius': '3px',
});
$('.btn-group').has('.btn:hidden').find('.btn:visible:last').css({
    'border-top-right-radius': '3px',
    'border-bottom-right-radius': '3px',
});
```

For each button group with hidden buttons, this will remove the border radii for all buttons within, and then add back border radii for the first and last visible buttons.

[OP's Fiddle with solution](http://jsfiddle.net/9h48vmrw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply duplicate the code and add an `hidden-xs` class the first code block and `visible-xs` to the other code block.

Like this:

```
<div class="btn-group hidden-xs" id="sortBtns" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">First</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Second</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Third</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fourth</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fifth</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sixth</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group visible-xs" id="sortBtns2" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">First</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Fifth</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sixth</button>
</div>
```

Another option is to apply the css rule to the edgy element:

```
  .edgy-right-element {
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  }
```

Comment: This sprung to mind, but it felt wrong.  I can also do it relatively easily using JavaScript to add a class based on what elements are visible (adding the class to the start and end buttons, perhaps), but that again feels a little unclean

Comment: @mikemike Added an other option